# Invisible decaying dark photon

Tags: dark-matter

I am interested in invisibly decaying dark photon to the dark sector.
Let's assume the particles in dark sector are dark photon ($\gamma_D$), dark matter (DM) , and long lived particle scalar ($\phi_D$).

Now, from my understanding, invisible dark photons are when dark photon decays to the particle in the dark sector. However, I will set that dark photon can decay to $\phi_D$ but not to DM. And finally, $\phi_D$ will decay to SM particle. In this case, do we say that dark photon is invisible since it decays to a long-lived particle in the dark sector (The life time of this particle is suppressed by the kinetic mixing parameter)? Or do you say this is visible decaying dark photon since it eventually decays to SM particle?

May be I am messing up with the definition of dark sector.

Thank you for your help!